# Use javascript variable as array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, variables, indexing

I have following code:

```
var n = 1;
var term = "${abc[n].term}";
console.log("term = " + term);
```

term seems to be empty, but if I replace 
`var term = "${abc[n].term}";` 
by
`var term = "${abc[1].term}";`
it works.

It looks like jsp is looking for the `n` property of the deck object, how could I fix it so that `n` is replaced by its value when I use is as array index ?

**Edit:**
It seems that it's not a good idea to try mixing JSTL and Javascript, and that if you want to use a javascript variable as array index, you must copy the object to an Array object, like this:

```
var deck = new Array();
<c:forEach var="v" items="${abc}">
    deck.push("${v.term}");
</c:forEach>

var n = 1;
console.log("term = " + deck[n]);
```

Comment: You can perfectly mix JavaScript with JSP/JSTL/EL. You should only **understand** that JSP/JSTL/EL runs in webserver and produces HTML code and that JavaScript is part of the produced HTML code which in turn runs in webbrowser. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. Do you see it now? You should write JSP/JSTL/EL code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using quotes properly, try this:

```
var term = "${abc[" + n +"].term}";
```

`"${abc[n].term}"` here n is considred as a part of the string not as your variable `n`. So try concatenating it.

Comment: Actually, that's what I tried at first but I get the following exception if I do that :java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " + n + " java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)

Comment: The `${...}` in JSP is used to evaluate server-side variables. You seem to have completely missed that point.